# Marketing Cloud Report: Count Email Send by Email Name, Month over Month - 1 Years Data

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, sql, analytics

I would like a report that counts the number of emails sent by month, by "email name".  Is there a tool that offers these metrics?  I know this can be accomplished using SQL joining _sent and job, but I'm only retrieving 6 months' worth of data and require a year's worth.  The email Tracking extract would not work here either as the report does not contain "Email Name."

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest [this method](https://sprignaturemoves.com/retrieving-and-storing-aggregated-send-data/), which mirrors the Send object (accessible via SOAP API) into a data extension.  It represents the entire history of sends and aggregated stats by ID (Job_id).  It also includes email name.

Steps:

1. Create the `Send` data extension
2. Create a SSJS Script Activity -- Just copy and paste the code from the site.  It assumes the target data Extension is named `Send`.
3. Create an Automation, add the Script Activity, and schedule it to run daily

You'll need to do the month-over-month part in Excel or with another Query Activity using the `Send` data extension as a source.

Also, triggered sends will be a problem in your month-over-month metrics -- as they do not get new Job IDs unless they're published.

Comment: You're the man Adam, thank you!